# How to Add Tabs at Front in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal-7

How should I add tabs at the front end in user profile. As I changed at back end but I can not find any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create your own module, the code will look like this:

```
function downloaded_menu(){ $items['user/%user/downloaded'] = array( 'title' => 'Downloaded', 'page callback' => 'downloaded_content_page', 'access arguments' => array('access content'), 'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 'weight' => 10, ); return $items; }


downloaded_content_page(){your code here}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look of hook_menu [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

you have to try with different type

```
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
```